# How to delete a windows media playlist programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using a C# application where I have to create a playlist. At the end of this application on form close I want to delete this play list which has been created. How do I do this?

what I want is `WMP.playlistCollection.remove("myplaylist");`

This is wrong and does not work. Is there something similar?

Comment: akash bhauu...jai maharashtra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to give `Playlist` object as the parameter

```
IWMPPlaylistArray plCollection = WMP.playlistCollection.getByName("myplaylist");
if (plCollection.count > 0)
{
    IWMPPlaylist pl = plCollection.Item(0);
    WMP.playlistCollection.remove(pl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WMP.playlistCollection.remove()
```

removes the playlist from windows media player, but the file are still present in the file system int the My Documents/MyMusic/My Playlists folder.

As stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564786(v=vs.85).aspx

"Remarks

This method deletes an item from the library. This method does not delete files from the user's computer."